# Retrieve All the XPATH from an xml using Vbscript or

Tags: vbscript, qtp

How can i retrieve all the valid XPATH from all these node?

----------------Sample XML---------------------

```
<name version="1.0">
<document>
<documentId>0107</documentId>
<NameDetail>
<firstname>SAM</firstname>
<internalreferenceNumber>12345</internalreferenceNumber>
</NameDetail>
<NameDetail>
<firstname>TECHNO</firstname>
<internalreferenceNumber>12346</internalreferenceNumber>
</NameDetail>
</document>
</name>
```

For the Above XML, the Output would be :

```
XPATH for name = "/name"
XPATH for documentId = "/document/documentId"
XPATH for firstname = ""/document/NameDetail[1]/firstname"
XPATH for firstname = "/document/NameDetail[2]/firstname"
```

Comment: What do you mean _retrieve XPATH_? There can be any number of XPath expressions that describe an XML element. Please add the expected results you want from QTP in this case.

Comment: I have updated my questions with more details itself.

Answer (score 0):

QTP does not support extracting XPaths from XML documents you would have to do so yourself as plain VBScript perhaps by using Microsoft's [XMLDOM object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx).

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject( "Microsoft.XMLDOM" )
```

Comment: I agree that we need to do it using XMLDOM parser. But it is a huge tidy work :)